# Can Azure AD users be used in a non-cloud Windows domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, entra-id

We have a bunch of bare-metal servers managed by a hosting company (UKFast).

On one of these we have a Domain Controller set up and the other servers are part of this domain (Windows 2012 R1 server).

At the moment we have set up users on this domain and can connect and authenticate (e.g. via RDP) with these users.

We would like to link our AzureAD logins, which are used to log into stand-alone Windows Desktops/Outlook 365 etc., into this configuration so that we can authenticate onto the servers using our AzureAD users/passwords.

**Is this possible**? Can it be done without upgrading the DC from 2012?

I did briefly look at [Azure Active Directory Connect](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47594), but it seems to be more about getting AD users onto AzureAD than the other way around and I couldn't get it work work on Windows 2012 anyhow.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that what you're looking for is a Hybrid Azure AD join scenario. I'm also fairly certain that you're going to need to use Azure AD Connect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Azure AD Connect to synchronize your Active Directory users with Azure AD, but not the other way around.

What the tool does is create an AAD user for each AD users, and keep them in sync; but if a user is created in AAD, there is no way to sync it back to the local AD, which will know nothing about it. Synchronization is strictly unidirectional (*), from AD to AAD.

(*) There are some exceptions, like password writeback; but there is no way to create AD users based on AAD ones.

---

That said, something can probably be hacked by exporting users from AAD and importing them into AD, and then modifying the appropriate attributes so that ADConnect can correctly map and synchronize them; but this would require extensive knowledge and development work.

Comment: I think what the OP wants to do is to login to his on premises domain joined servers using Azure AD credentials, which is possible natively with Windows 10 devices with Hybrid Azure AD Join. Hybrid Azure AD Join is supported on Windows Server 2008 and forward, so it should be possible but probably requires Azure Ad Connect for down level (non-Windows 10) devices.

Comment: @joeqwerty hybrid join allows *devices* to work with both AD and AAD; but the user account of whoever uses them needs to exist in AD, and be synchronized to AAD; the OP's problem is that the user accounts have been created directly in AAD and don't exist in AD, a situation that ADConnect can't solve.

Comment: "You can use Azure AD Connect to synchronize your Active Directory users with Azure AD, but not the other way around." - but it really is the other way around that I'm asking about here....

Comment: @mark I understand perfectly what you are asking; but unfortunately the answer is "no, this is not possible".

Comment: At least for now. Who know what Microsoft might introduce later? Azure is constantly evolving. But currently there isn't any supported way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably what I need:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-forest-trust

Comment: Nope. This solution (which is quite technically complex and still in preview) does the exact opposite of what you want: it lets your AD users access resources in Azure. You could log on to an Azure VM using an AD user account. But you still would not be able to use an AAD user account to access an on-premises computer.